# Unwind Segue Issue

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, segue

I was following this tutorial to understand unwind segues

http://pragmaticstudio.com/blog/2013/2/5/unwind-segues

Everything works fine until the end:

```
- (IBAction)completeSignIn:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
   DSTSignInViewController *signInVC = segue.sourceViewController;
   self.greetingLabel.text = signInVC.signInName;
}
```

I get the error "Unknown type name "DSTSignInViewController"

Comment: Is this a runtime error or compile time error? If it is runtime, is `DSTSignInViewController.m` included in your target?

Comment: yes its included in my target.. should I be importing DSTSignInViewController but I thought not importing is the point of an unwind segue

Comment: If you reference it you need to import it, otherwise the compiler doesn't know that it exists. Unwind segues have nothing to do with whether or not you import a header.

Comment: this is what the tutorial says:The challenge is that we don't want scene two's view controller to import the header file for scene one's view controller, which would lead to an overly-coupled design. Traditionally we've solved this problem by creating a delegate protocol for scene two. Scene one then sets itself to be scene two's delegate. More recently, we've also been able to use blocks to pass the behavior from scene one to scene two.

Comment: Sounds like you want to create a protocol that defines the `signInName` property then. Your `DSTSignInViewController` would then conform to said protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the discussion in the comments... It sounds like you want something like the following.

```
@protocol DSTSSignInController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString signInName;

@end
```

And then

```
- (IBAction)completeSignIn:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
   UIViewController<DSTSSignInController> *signInVC = segue.sourceViewController;
   self.greetingLabel.text = signInVC.signInName;
}
```

This way you can just import the header that defines the `DSTSSignInController` protocol and not `DSTSignInViewController` or any other possible implementations/conformers.